# Giving different number variables to different browsers in Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am trying to give different numbers to each of my clients. When I click the button on first browser it must say `usernumber is 1` and when I do this in second browser I expect it to say `usernumber is 2`. It actually says `usernumber is 2` but only when I press the button twice or more.

After I press the button on second browser, I open the first browser and press the button, now it says `usernumber is 2` and when I press two or more times it says `usernumber is 1`.

So it is not stable at all and I always have to press this button to keep it in correct value.

If you run my files you will see what I mean better. I use google chrome, my express version is 3.0.0 and my socket.io version is 0.9.16.

---

Here is my app.js and index.html files:

### Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title> client number </title>

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var ax;
jQuery(function($) {
  var socket = io.connect();

  socket.emit('getbrowser1', {});
  socket.on('getbrowser1f', function(data) {
    ax = data;
  });

  var butondene1 = document.getElementById("butondene1");
  butondene1.addEventListener('click', function() {
    socket.emit('getbrowser1', {});
    document.getElementById("playerwho").innerHTML = "usernumber is " + ax;
  });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>

<button id="butondene1">butondeneme1</button>
<text  id="playerwho">player who ? </text>
</body>
</html>
```

### App.js

```
var express = require('express'),
  app = express(),
  server = require('http').createServer(app),
  io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

var usernumm = 0;
var usernum1 = [];

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/'));

server.listen((process.env.PORT || 5000));

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  var endpoint = socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].address;

  console.log('***New connection from ' + endpoint.address + ':' + endpoint.port);

  usernumm++;
  usernum1[usernumm] = endpoint.port;

  console.log('usernum' + usernumm + 'geldi' + findusernum());

  socket.on('disconnect', function() {
    usernumm--;

    console.log('***Client disconnected');
  });


  socket.on('getbrowser1', function(data) {
    var a = findusernum();
    io.sockets.emit('getbrowser1f', a);
  });

  //finds number of online users

  function findusernum() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
      if (usernum1[i] == endpoint.port) {
        return i;
      } else {}
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: You should write which versions of express, socket.io  and what browser you are using. When i try your code then the app crashes because `socket.manager` is `undefined`.

Comment: I added them on my question.

Comment: Before your second edit you wrote that you use `socket.io`  `0.9` but now you write `1.3.7`.  In `0.9`  `socket.manager`  exists, but in `1.3.7` or new it does not exist anymore so with `1.3.7` your code should not run at all because it will throw an exception at `socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].address`.

Comment: Sorry, I confused. It is 0.9.16. I am sure.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your described behaviour, but `endpoint.port` will not necessarily be different for different clients. You might want to use an `uuid` instead.

Beside that you have diffent logical problem within your code.

When a connection happens you write:

```
usernumm++;
usernum1[usernumm] = endpoint.port;
```

And on disconnect you have:

```
usernumm--;
```

Lets assume you have the following connection order:

```
UserA connects (usernumm++ => 1)
UserB connects (usernumm++ => 2)

UserA disconnects (usernumm-- => 1)
UserC connects (usernumm++ => 2) << here you overwrite the data of UserB
```

Beside that you have:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   if (usernum1[i] == endpoint.port) {
     return i;
   } else {}
}
```

The *problem* here is that you start the loop at `0` but the index `0` of our `usernum1` is always `undefined` because you use your `usernumm` after the increment. It is not necessarily a problem here, but it makes the code hard to read because you would assume that there are at a maximum 4 users but actually you can only have 3.

But back to your problem instead of `socket.manager.handshaken[socket.id].address` you can either use an incrementing number (depends on how long your service will run) or an uuid or random number that is not used by an already connected user.

Comment: I understood what you mean. But somehow  I can get different ports from different browsers. My actual point is that what is it with clicking twice ? I didn't get the logic of clicking twice or more.

Comment: @B.ÖNER I'm now able to reproduce the problem, I'll check what the problem is.

Comment: My problem is about the order of codes runned in app.js and html. I guess it runs codes in html from top to buttom and then code on app.js file from top to the bottom. I could solve my problem by delaying my fuction via `setTimeout`.index.